# Cannot switch to Nvidia graphic card on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have:

- Laptop:         **Asus K95**
- OS:             **Ubuntu 18.04**
- Dedicated GPU:  **Nvidia GeForce GT 635M**
- Integrated GPU: **Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)**

As you, probably, may guess my trouble is that i cannot switch from intel graphics to the nvidia. I have nvidia-driver-390 installed and in use(checked in Softwares & Update -> Additional Drivers).

```
➜  ~ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DE3sv00001043sd000010CCbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

➜  ~ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia

➜  ~ prime-select query
nvidia
```

but system, seems, is still using intel graphics(checked in Settings -> About). Also i have troubles when:

```
➜  ~ nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system
```

Should admit that only 2 items are present in nvidia x server settings' PRIME Profiles: NVIDIA(chosen) and Intel. And nothing else, no other items or menu sub-items.

```
(nvidia-settings:18439): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:56:09.612: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 22:56:09.616: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 22:56:09.616: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 22:56:09.662: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|query
** Message: 22:56:09.662: PRIME: on-demand mode: "0"
** Message: 22:56:09.663: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? no
```

BTW, right now i am using wayland environment, because Xorg cannot start with installed nvidia drivers - push me back to the login dialog every time i try to log in to the system, however it works with xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(with intel gpu off course). Brief look in the nano /var/log/Xorg.0.log returns:

```
[    22.800] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.801]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.801]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    22.801] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    22.801] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    22.801] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    22.801] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    22.801] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    22.801] (EE)
[    22.818] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I tried to install bumblebee, but it causes full freezing of the graphic environment a moment after logging-in with Xorg. I had to purge it.
Please, help to use Nvidia!

UPDATED:

```
➜  ~ glxinfo | grep OpenGL          
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Please add output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to your question. I see no problems at all.

Comment: i've added. The problem is that i cannot use my nvidia adapter and ought to use in-built intel.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to follow these steps [here](https://frl.nyu.edu/tutorials-for-installing-ubuntu-18-04-dual-system-and-nvidia-driver-cuda-pytorch-gpu-toolchain/)

Answer (score 0):

[Install the latest NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1376336/78223):

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-495
```

and run:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

to automatically configure your X configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of dancing around I decided to install Windows with appropriate drivers for this video card. And I failed. So I can assert that the main problem is that my video card... is broken.